# Poetry config for torch installation

Tags: python, pytorch, python-poetry

I have the following poetry config for installing torch

```
torch = [
    # Mac with apple silicon
    { markers = "sys_platform == 'darwin'", version = "^2.0.1", source = "pypi" },
    # Mac with arm docker container
    { markers = "sys_platform == 'linux' and platform_machine == 'aarch64'", version = "^2.0.1", source = "pypi" },
    # Mac with x86_64 container with cpu version ony
    { markers = "sys_platform == 'linux' and platform_machine != 'aarch64'", version = "^2.0.1+cpu", source = "pytorch" }
]
```

However this doesn't seem to work for installation, if I check with export
`poetry export -f requirements.txt --output requirements.txt`

```
torch==2.0.1+cpu ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "3.11" and (sys_platform == "darwin" or sys_platform == "linux")
```

which is plain wrong. To make this work, I manually have to pin the versions like so

```
torch = [
    # Mac apple silicon
    { markers = "sys_platform == 'darwin'", url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-2.0.1-cp310-none-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl" },
    # Mac docker arm container
    { markers = "sys_platform == 'linux' and platform_machine == 'aarch64'", url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch-2.0.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl" },
    # Mac with x86_64 container
    { markers = "sys_platform == 'linux' and platform_machine == 'x86_64'", url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-2.0.1%2Bcpu-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl" },
]
```

This generates

```
torch @ https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-2.0.1%2Bcpu-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl ; sys_platform == "linux" and platform_machine == "x86_64" and python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "3.11"
torch @ https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-2.0.1-cp310-none-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "3.11" and sys_platform == "darwin"
torch @ https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch-2.0.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl ; sys_platform == "linux" and platform_machine == "aarch64" and python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "3.11"
```

I lose the nice upgrades if I decide to upgrade with poetry and have to manually upgrade the urls each time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like it should be a tiny fix... if it gets accepted: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry-plugin-export/pull/234